# How to get index item of array in emberjs view

Tags: ember.js

How to get index item of array in an emberjs view.

This returns an error:

```
{{#view}}
  {{oneArray[0]}}
{{/view}}
```

I don't want to use {{#each}} to show all items, just want to show the special index item. How?

Or can I get the index of {{#each}}?

```
{{#each oneArray}}
    {{#if index>0}}
         don't show the first item {{oneArray[index]}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: `{{#if}}` can not contain a comparison afaik. it will check for a falsy variable. i.e. `null`, `false`, `undefined` or `[]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in [this article](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/), you can define a new array for including the index in each row:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    oneArrayWithIndices: function() {
      return this.get('oneArray').map(function(item, index) {
        return {item: i, index: idx};
      });
    }.property('oneArray.@each')
});
```

and then in your template you can access the index like so:

```
{{#each view.oneArrayWithIndices}}
  index: {{this.index}} <br />   
  item: {{this.item}}
{{/#each}}
```

However, since you just want to show specific items from the array, it is better to do it in your view (or even better in your controller). *Try to keep your templates logic-less*.

Therefore, create a new array in your view/controller that includes only the items you want to show:

```
myFilteredArray: function() {
  return this.get('oneArray').filter( function(item, index) {
    // return true if you want to include this item
    // for example, with the code below we include all but the first item
    if (index > 0) { 
      return true;     
    }    
  });
}.property('oneArray.@each')
```