# How to get object at index in Array Controller within view?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that has an Array Controller as a property. I would like to get an element at an index within the view.

view:

`{{ App.array.firstObject }}`

works but:

`{{ App.array.objectAt(1) }}`

doesn't work. I can't iterate in my case.

So is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `{{App.array.[1]}}` work for you ?

Comment: no...in the view things work as if you are calling the get() function for each method. For instance: `{{App.array[1]}}` actually calls `App.get('array[1]'` which leads to an error. I wonder if there's compatible way for indexing.

Comment: sorry, I missed something... App.array.[1]

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/pvemJ/ You can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502300/how-to-get-index-item-of-array-in-emberjs-view

Comment: Ahh ok arrays, I was working with array controller.... `{{App.array.content.[1]}}` works