# Get Object By Index In Ember.js with Fixture Adapter

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This has been driving me nuts all day. I've created a flip game that will be an installation in a hardware store.

I've set my model for my route to get all "hwstores" that I setup with the fixtures adapter:

```
window.FlipGame = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

FlipGame.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

FlipGame.Hwstore = DS.Model.extend({
  number: DS.attr('string'),
  score: DS.attr('number'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.attr('string')
});

FlipGame.Hwstore.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, number: 1234, score: 1000, city: 'Houston', country: 'USA' },
  { id: 2, number: 4321, score: 2000, city: 'Miami', country: 'USA' },
  { id: 3, number: 9999, score: 9999, city: 'Portland', country: 'USA' }
];


FlipGame.WelcomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(controller){
    return this.store.find('hwstore');
  }
});
```

The end goal is to get the top three stores with the highest score.

I'm using the ember extension for chrome, so I can see that all three of my objects are in the "model" object within my view. But for some unbelievably stupid reason, I can only get the first and last of the objects using "firstObject" and "lastObject". There is no way to get the middle object. I have tried every syntax I can possibly think of.

This works:

```
<p class="lead">Store {{firstObject.number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{firstObject.city}}, {{firstObject.country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{firstObject.score}}</strong></p>
```

This also works:

```
<p class="lead">Store {{lastObject.number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{lastObject.city}}, {{lastObject.country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{lastObject.score}}</strong></p>
```

None of these work:

```
<p class="lead">Store {{objectAt(1).number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{objectAt(1).city}}, {{objectAt(1).country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{objectAt(1).score}}</strong></p>

<p class="lead">Store {{[1].number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{[1].city}}, {{[1].country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{[1].score}}</strong></p>

<p class="lead">Store {{this.model.[1].number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{this.model.[1].city}}, {{this.model.[1].country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{this.model.[1].score}}</strong></p>

<p class="lead">Store {{model.objectAt(1).number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{model.objectAt(1).city}}, {{model.objectAt(1).country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{model.objectAt(1).score}}</strong></p>
```

Before you answer, realize that I am not able to use {{#each}} {{/each}} syntax, because the markup for each store will be drastically different from each other, and will need to be in a different order.

There is a stack question very similar here: [How to get object at index in Array Controller within view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724272/how-to-get-object-at-index-in-array-controller-within-view)

But, it does not answer my question. None of the suggestions works.

Also, the ember extension for Chrome shows that the "model" object type is:

```
<DS.RecordArray:ember356>
```

There is also a special way to inspect the object in the console. What really infuriates me is that in the console, I can do ($E is the temporary variable name for my object):

```
$E.objectAt(1).get('number')
```

and it works fine!!! If I try the same thing in the template:

```
{{this.model.objectAt(1).get('number')}}
```

it will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think it's rare that someone knows an individual item in an array that's somehow unique.  Generally the use case is the first/last item is special and you know something about it possibly.  Even if the items needed to be rendered differently you would generally ascertain this from some property on the model and do something like

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{#if item.isColor}}
    {{render 'color' item}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if item.isDuck}}
     {{render 'duck' item}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

But in your case if there are the top three items, and you know each one is special somehow, then the easiest way would be to just add a computed property in your controller

```
App.WelcomeController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  secondObject: function(){
    return this.objectAt(1);
  }.property('model.[]')
});
```

That obviously assumes that there are at least 2 objects, but then in the `welcome` template you can refer to everything as `firstObject`, `secondObject`, and `lastObject`

```
<p class="lead">Store {{secondObject.number}}</p>
<p class="lead">{{secondObject.city}}, {{secondObject.country}}</p>
<p class="score"><strong>{{secondObject.score}}</strong></p>
```

Or you could have even more fun and do:

```
App.WelcomeController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  first: function(){
    return this.objectAt(0);
  }.property('model.[]'),

  second: function(){
    return this.objectAt(1);
  }.property('model.[]'),

  third: function(){
    return this.objectAt(2);
  }.property('model.[]')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, kingpin2k. This does exactly what I want. I find the syntax pretty confusing though. .property('model.[]') Not very intuitive, :/

Comment: totally, so that last part is saying it's a computed property, and it depends on the model's items, aka any time one of them is added or removed this property is dirty and should be recomputed.  You could have also had it empty `.property()` and it would have computed once, and then never been dirty (which might be correct in your situation if your array of items are never changing).  Or you also could do `.property('model.length')` any time the length changes (which is the same as `model.[]`).

Comment: Additionally you could say, hey this property is dirty if one of any of the properties on any of the models in the collection is dirty, something like `property('model.@each.fooProperty')`.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/ & http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: Thanks, again for the follow up comments! I'll take a look at those docs.