# How to display (in a view) a list subset with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of objects, fetched via Ajax from an API. It is something similar to this:

```
App.Card = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: "",
  color: ""
});

App.cardsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],

  createCard: function(data) {
    this.pushObject(App.Card.create(data));
  },

  loadCards: function() {
    // Fetch API and use createCard
  }
});
```

When I use `{{#each App.cardsController}}`, I list all cards inside my controller.

**But I'd like to filter them by color. How can I filter a list (inside a Controller's content) and display them?**

I tried this approach:

Added this code inside `App.cardsController`:

```
  filterCardsByColor: function() {
    array = this.get('content').filter(function(item, index) {
      return item.get('color') == 'red';
    });
    return array;
  }.property('content.@each')
```

And added `{{#each App.cardsController.filterCardsByColor}}` to my view.

But I am getting the following error at my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' ember.min.js:18
```

What I am doing wrong? Or what should I do? Should I move that logic to a view? How? I even tried wrapping `array` inside `Ember.Array.create(array)`, but it didn't solved my issue.

*Bonus: is it someway possible to send a parameter to filterCardsByColor, so I can ask for `'red'` cards, or for `'yellow'` cards, etc?*

Comment: Note: I tried to use the "myFilteredArray` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502300/how-to-get-index-item-of-array-in-emberjs-view -- I guess I am not using it correctly.

Comment: Which version of Ember.js are you using? Defining computed properties is not possible anymore for Ember.Object.create

Comment: @Luan: I'm using 1.0.0-pre4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to store an array that will hold the colours to filter out *(or to filter in, if you wish)*, and have the computed property update every time its `length` changes by specifying `.property('colours.length');`:

```
filteredContent: function() {
    // Triggered every time a colour is added/removed.
    var colours = this.get('colours');
    return this.get('content').filter(function(model) {
        // Determine whether the current model's colour is in the array of those filtered.
        return Boolean(jQuery.inArray(model.get('colour'), colours) == -1);
    });
}.property('colours.length')
```

We then just need a way for our view to be able to pass in colours to add to that array. We can do this with a different function called `applyFilters` that will accept one argument -- the colour we wish to exclude. You can pass in this colour in an `{{action}}` like so: `<a {{action "applyFilter" "red"}}>`.

```
applyFilter: function(colour) {
    var colours = this.get('colours');
    if (!colour) {
        // Clear all of the colours if we're clearing the filters.
        colours.clear();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise we can push the new colour into the array, which will trigger
    // an update of the filteredContent computed property.
    colours.pushObject(colour);
}
```

Fully working JSFiddle for you to mess around with: http://jsfiddle.net/9XmqL/

Comment: Thank you, so much! If I could, I'd give you extra points for creating that jsfiddle snippet :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think WildHoney's is the best answer.

Adding the following to their CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes onUpdate { 
    from { background: yellow; }
}
@keyframes onUpdate { 
    from { background: yellow; }
}
* { 
    -webkit-animation: onUpdate 1s; 
    animation: onUpdate 1s;
}
```

I can see that when the content is updated, the entire list gets redrawn.  For very long lists, this can be a severe performance hit.

To avoid this, you should only generate the array providing filteredContent once - when the pointer to content changes - and update it in a targetted manner, based on changes to the subset.

See http://jsfiddle.net/wRzRn/2/

Comment: It all depends on the use case. If you're generating long lists of anything, then there are extra considerations to take into account across the board. In development you should start with the most basic implementation, and then adapt based on the requirements -- unless the requirement from the beginning is to handle large datasets.